# Nest can't resolve dependencies LogService (?, LogFormatProvider). Please argument String at index [0] is available in the AppModule context

Tags: typescript, logging, graphql, nestjs

```
My app.module.ts file looks like this:

import { Module, HttpModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { join } from 'path';
import { LaunchService } from './launch/launch.service';
import { LaunchResolver } from './launch/launch.resolver';
import { LaunchModule } from './launch/launch.module';
import { LogService } from '@fmr-pr103625/nest-scaffold';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: { path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts') },
    }),
    HttpModule,
    LaunchModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, LaunchService, LaunchResolver, LogService],
})
export class AppModule {}


My app.service.ts file looks like this:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Logger, LogService } from '@fmr-pr103625/nest-scaffold';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  @Logger()
  private logger: LogService;
  getHello(): string {
    this.logger.error('Hello');
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}


I am trying to use the in built logservice from another repo but this error is coming while running the file.

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LogService (?, LogFormatProvider). Please make sure that the argument String at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If String is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If String is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing String */ ]
  })
```

---------------------------**********************---------------------------------

Let me know what i have missed, how i can solve this.
I am just checking the simple LogService.

--------------------------**********************-----------------------------------

Log Service looks like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.LogService = void 0;
const tslib_1 = require("tslib");
const common_1 = require("@nestjs/common");
const winston = require("winston");
const log_level_1 = require("../constants/log-level");
const log_format_service_1 = require("./log-format.service");
const Console = winston.transports.Console;
let LogService = class LogService {
    constructor(category, formatProvider) {
        this.category = category;
        this.formatProvider = formatProvider;
        this.level = log_level_1.LogLevel.info;
        this.logger = winston.createLogger({
            level: this.level,
            format: this.formatProvider.createFormat(this.category),
            transports: [new Console()],
        });
    }
    info(message, ...meta) {
        this.log(log_level_1.LogLevel.info, message, ...meta);
    }
    error(message, ...meta) {
        this.log(log_level_1.LogLevel.error, this.addingSplit(meta, message), ...meta);
    }
    warn(message, ...meta) {
        this.log(log_level_1.LogLevel.warn, message, ...meta);
    }
    debug(message, ...meta) {
        this.log(log_level_1.LogLevel.debug, message, ...meta);
    }
    log(level, message, ...meta) {
        this.syncProps();
        if (this.isLevelEnabled(level))
            this.logger.log(level, message, ...meta);
    }
    isLevelEnabled(loggingLevel) {
        return this.logger.levels[this.level] >= this.logger.levels[loggingLevel];
    }
    syncProps() {
        this.logger.level = this.level;
    }
    addingSplit(meta, message) {
        if (meta[0] instanceof Error && meta[0].message) {
            message = message + ", errorMessage:";
        }
        return message;
    }
};
tslib_1.__decorate([
    config_core_1.Prop(),
    tslib_1.__metadata("design:type", String)
], LogService.prototype, "level", void 0);
LogService = tslib_1.__decorate([
    common_1.Injectable(),
    tslib_1.__metadata("design:paramtypes", [String, log_format_service_1.LogFormatProvider])
], LogService);
exports.LogService = LogService;
```

---------------------------*************************-------------------------------

Comment: What does your `LoggerService` look like? Looks like Nest is trying to create an instance of it, but doesn't know what to inject for it

Comment: Could you show the `LoggerService` and it purpose? and why you not use Logger of `nestjs` instead?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, I have added the LogService

Comment: @Krish the compiled JS isn't the most useful. What package is this from?

The reason you are getting the error is because the dependencies aren't included. Most likely you should be importing an entire module vs just adding the LogService to the providers.

Comment: @RobertC Let me know how i can solve this, i am new to nestjs

Comment: Well, Nest is trying to inject something for `category` but it's reading the injection token as `String` (the type of the parameter) and there's no provider found for `String`. There should be a metadata token set for that `category` and you should _probably_ be using a dynamic provider approach for this setup. Take a look at [ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) to see _a_ solution for this. There's also a good article on dev.to about dynamic providers that may be helpful to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message ***Nest can't resolve dependencies LogService (?, LogFormatProvider).*** is telling you that you are requiring a string value to be passed into the constructor of the LogService as its first argument.  This would be the *category* argument.  During the injection process, it does not know what it should provide for that argument.  Normally, you would want to avoid such a constructor design, but if it is required, then you will need to make allowances for providing a default value.  (As an Architect/Tech Lead, I usually instruct my devs to simplify the signature by using application configuration values.)

Let's take a look at the cause of the issue in a unit testing environment, which you should be able to duplicate and use the unit test to help you resolve the issue.  You would set up your testingModule to provide the injection support for you, and it might look like this:

```
testingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [LogService]
}).compile();

logService = testingModule.get(LogService);
```

How is the injector supposed to know what you want to supply for the *category* argument?  That is where the @Inject() decorator can help.  In your constructor, add **@Inject('LOG_CATEGORY')** in front of your *category* argument.  This lets the injector know that when it instantiates the *LogService* you want to provide a value via the name "LOG_CATEGORY".

```
constructor(@Inject('LOG_CATEGORY') category: string, ...) {...}
```

Now let's change the *testingModule* to provide a value.  In the *providers* array, provide a provider which specifies the value you want to use.  In the example below, I want to provide the value "Default" for the category.

```
testingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    LogService,
    {
      provide: 'LOG_CATEGORY',
      useValue: 'Default'
    }
  ]
}).compile();

logService = testingModule.get(LogService);
```

How you choose to address the issue is up to you, but I hope this sheds a little light on one way you might go about resolving it.  In the very least, it should give you an example on how to resolve such a case in a unit test.  :D